# SwiftUI: Getting array of string from another view

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui

I have a view called TagView which creates a list of tags using `LazyHGrid` I am trying to get the array of tags that loads from the web service and pass it from the main view to `TagView`. Here is the code:

```
struct TagsView: View {

var tags: Array<String>
private var layout = [GridItem(.fixed(30))]

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Spacer()
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            
                    LazyHGrid(rows: layout) {
                        ForEach(tags, id: \.self) {
                            Button("\($0)") {
                                
                            }
                            .font(.callout.bold())

                        }
                    }
                }
           }
```

After creating the variable: `var tags: Array<String>` I need to get the array from the main view like this:

```
struct MainView: View {
    var model: Model
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TagsView(tags: model.tags)
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> TagsView' initializer is inaccessible due to 'private' protection
> level

I tried with `@Binding` and still no luck, any help would be great!

Comment: show the code of how you pass `model` into your `MainView`.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine the networking part is not yet done but assume something like this: `@State private var array = [String]()
                                                      init() {
array = model.tags
 }`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is that the synthesized `init` is being marked **private** since one of the properties is **private**. To solve the problem, remove the **private** or add:

```
init(tags: Array<String>) {
    self.tags = tags
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change `layout` to a `let` constant:

```swift
    private let layout = [GridItem(.fixed(30))]
```

Then the auto-generated init will not be private.

Answer (score 1):

Using Generate memberwise initializer fixed the problem:

```
internal init(tags: Array<String>) {
        self.tags = tags
    }
```

[image]